# Suppose that $\int_0^1 f(t) \textrm{d}t=21$, calculate $\int_0^\frac{1}{8} f(8t) \textrm{d}t$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose that $\int_0^1 f(t) \textrm{d}t=21$.
Calculate then $\int_0^\frac{1}{8} f(8t) \textrm{d}t$.

**My work**
Suppose $y=8t$, then when $t=0$ we have $y=0$ and $t=\frac{1}{8} $ implies $y=1$.
This gives $\int_{0}^\frac{1}{8} f(y) = 1$.

But I'm not sure if that correct , please help.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing, which is the correct approach, is called integration by change of variable, in case you want to Google it. You got almost everything right except that $dy = 8 dt$, implying that $dt=\frac{dy}{8}$. So
$$\int_0^{1/8} f(8t)dt=\int_0^1f(y)\frac{dy}{8}=
\frac{\int_0^1f(y)dy}{8}=\frac{\int_0^1f(t)dt}{8}=\frac{21}{8}\cdot$$

Comment: how you got f(y) =21 , I think it should equal 1

Comment: I am not assuming that. I added a couple of more steps that should clarify that point.

Comment: ok thank you I understand now

Comment: @user155971 Intuitively, you have the same "distribution" of heights, compressed into an width which is $8$ times smaller, so the area is $8$ times smaller. General integration by substitution uses essentially this same idea, but where the amount of "compression" (or "dilation") varies across the interval.